# Errors when patching an entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm usin' cakephp 3.6 & tryin' to edit some entity fields before save it, so when I use pathchEntity to edit those fields:

```html
$booking->set([
    'status'  => 1,
    'deposit' => $this->request->getData('deposit')
]);
```

I got errors of entity validation before save it, so how I should do to edit those fields without gettin' errors;

```
\src\Controller\BookingsController.php (line 253)
[
    'property_id' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'deposit' => [
        'fileType' => 'Veuillez introduire un fichier de type: PDF, JPG.'
    ],
    'last_name' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'first_name' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'phone' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'travelers_count' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'travelers_type' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'start' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'end' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'nights_count' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'discount' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'total' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ],
    'total_discount' => [
        '_required' => 'This field is required'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please add more details on the error

Comment: Like I said, the error is the validation errors (like **user_id is required**)

Comment: Can you share the **full and exact** messages?

Comment: Please add that to the question: Keep in mind StackOverflow is not a chat box, but a knowledge database. The question should be well documented easy to read for future users.

Comment: @DirkHorsten I added that in the second part of my question (under my code :) ).

Comment: @NicoHaase for sure: https://ibb.co/cjZFap, like I said it's a validation errors in the case where those fields was not empty on the entity

Comment: Please add all validation errors that occur to the question, not to the comment section and not as an image

Comment: @NicoHaase https://pastebin.com/pnAzaHH7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this error because you may have defined the below rule in your model.

```
$validator->requirePresence('user_id');
```

This checks validation on both create and update operations. You can change that as below

```
$validator->requirePresence('user_id', 'create');
```

This means **The field’s presence is required when validating a create operation.**

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that helped me a lot :)